Private POA geth network fails to start after a sudden shutdown of all nodes
I have a private POA Geth network consisting of three nodes. Due to power issue, all the nodes shut down simultaneously.
After the restart of nodes I am getting this error on all three nodes when i try to restart the geth.
INFO [10-06|11:33:49.309] Set global gas cap                       cap=50,000,000
WARN [10-06|11:33:49.309] Sanitizing invalid miner gas price       provided=0 updated=0
INFO [10-06|11:33:49.309] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=154.00MiB dirty=256.00MiB
INFO [10-06|11:33:49.309] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/root/POA_Blockchain/private_blockchain/data/geth/chaindata cache=512.00MiB handles=131,072
WARN [10-06|11:33:49.376] Truncating dangling head                 database=/root/POA_Blockchain/private_blockchain/data/geth/chaindata/ancient table=diffs indexed=124.23MiB stored=124.23MiB
INFO [10-06|11:33:49.380] Opened ancient database                  database=/root/POA_Blockchain/private_blockchain/data/geth/chaindata/ancient readonly=false
INFO [10-06|11:33:49.391] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 12023 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 0 EIP155: 0 EIP158: 0 Byzantium: 0 Constantinople: 0 Petersburg: 0 Istanbul: 0, Muir Glacier: <nil>, Berlin: <nil>, London: <nil>, Arrow Glacier: <nil>, MergeFork: <nil>, Engine: clique}"
INFO [10-06|11:33:49.397] Initialising Ethereum protocol           network=12023 dbversion=8
INFO [10-06|11:33:49.446] Loaded most recent local header          number=27,737,090 hash=22b009..7f61dc td=55,474,181 age=1mo1w6d
INFO [10-06|11:33:49.446] Loaded most recent local full block      number=367,409    hash=5280c6..7661d8 td=734,819    age=1y1w3d
INFO [10-06|11:33:49.446] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=27,737,090 hash=22b009..7f61dc td=55,474,181 age=1mo1w6d
ERROR[10-06|11:33:49.446] Truncating ancient chain                 from=27,737,090 to=367,409
WARN [10-06|11:33:49.446] Rewinding blockchain                     target=367,409

My environment:
Geth: v1.10.14
OS:
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.10 (Ootpa)"
